# Convert 32-bit TGA to PNG

Tags: php

I am working from [this code](http://de77.com/php/open-tga-with-php-imagecreatefromtga) and taking into account the comments to "fix" it for 32-bit, but it seems to still not work. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the [TGA descriptor](http://gshaw.ca/closecombat/formats/tga.html). This will have bits 0-3 as the alpha channel depth which will always be 8 for 32 bit, and the code doesn't account for that.

I tried to understand how to piece it together using [this C code](http://git.enlightenment.org/legacy/imlib2.git/plain/src/modules/loaders/loader_tga.c?id=12a35d6baeca394fc30b34278943bfec77bb7571) as a guide, but no luck.

It seems the once you take into account the pixel being of length of 4 (as per the patch in comments) his `dwordize` only accounts for 3 of the 4 bytes, the 4th byte being the alpha bits I think.

I tried changing the function from

```
function dwordize($str)
{
    $a = ord($str[0]);
    $b = ord($str[1]);
    $c = ord($str[2]);
    return $c*256*256 + $b*256 + $a;
}
```

to

```
function dwordize($str)
{
    $a = ord($str[0]);
    $b = ord($str[1]);
    $c = ord($str[2]);
    $d = ord($str[3]);
    return $d*256*256*256 + $c*256*256 + $b*256 + $a;
}
```

which didn't work, and then tried

```
function dwordize($str)
{
    $a = ord($str[0]);
    $b = ord($str[1]);
    $c = ord($str[2]);
    $d = ord($str[3]);
    return $c*256*256 + $b*256 + $a + $d*256*256*256;
}
```

All of which I am trying to go off the C code which goes from like RBGA to BGRA and then the indices are all weird. I really don't understand the C code enough to apply it to the PHP code.

I also found [this site](http://www.ryanjuckett.com/programming/parsing-colors-in-a-tga-file/) which may help, I am reading it over now and if I come up with anything I will update.

Comment: If you can use named hyperlinks, as per a normal webpage, it makes things rather more readable; see my edit. +1

Comment: This looks like an interesting task. I will try to help you. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Can you give us the input TGA image so that we can perform some tests that will make us sure the result is what you want. Meanwhile I'll just use some random TGA file

Comment: a 32-bit TGA file I have used was https://www.dropbox.com/s/gv4loz4nuwj2830/eyebrows.tga - Here is a 24-bit TGA file that seems to work fine: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4e1wa5crja9jvt/224op.tga

Comment: Thank, indeed 24 bits TGA images seem to work. I have found a few issues so far, but fixing them led me to have different results but still not the expected result.

Comment: Ok I almost got it :) So far here is what I have: https://www.sendspace.com/file/6qe3xk

Comment: Ok I have found the solution, I'm writing my answer now.

Comment: Et voilà :) Please give me a feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found your solution. There were missing adjustments that needed to be made in the RLE decode function to support the 32 bits pixel format: i.e: `AARRGGBB`

So first of all we need to bypass the color depth check of your library as suggested in the comments, so we change the check to this on **line `99`**

```
if ($header['pixel_size'] != 24 && $header['pixel_size'] != 32) {
    die('Unsupported TGA color depth'); 
}
```

Then we need to change some variables that are color depth dependent. Most of them will be used for data formatting so we need them to have the correct value regardless of the color depth.
So that would be:

**line `104` :** `$bytes = $header['pixel_size'] / 8;`

**line `117` :** `$size = $header['width'] * $header['height'] * $bytes;`

**line `154` :** `$pixels = str_split($data, $bytes);`

**and remove the line `153`:** `$num_bytes = $header['pixel_size']/8;` We do not need it anymore.

---

Then we will need the `rle_decode()` function to know the pixel format size, so int the `for` loop when we call it we need to pass this parameter, so we need to change as well the following line:

**line `141`:** `$data = rle_decode($data, $size, $bytes);`

Therefore the function prototypes changes into:

**line `9`**: `function rle_decode($data, $datalen, $pixel_size)`

Now you can see on this function there are multiple `3` ***magic numbers*** (i.e: `for ($j = 0; $j<3*$value; $j++)` **on line 29**).
All of those must be replaced by the pixel size parameter. (**3** for `24 bits` and **4** for `32 bits`)

Moreover sometimes it will write only ***3*** bytes instead of ***4*** when creating the pixels so we must adjust that as well.

So finally this gives us the following algorithm:

```
function rle_decode($data, $datalen, $pixel_size)
{
    $len = strlen($data);

    $out = '';

    $i = 0;
    $k = 0;
    while ($i<$len)
    {
        dec_bits(ord($data[$i]), $type, $value);
        if ($k >= $datalen)
        {
            break;
        }

        $i++;

        if ($type == 0) //raw
        {
            for ($j=0; $j<$pixel_size*$value; $j++)
            {
                $out .= $data[$j+$i];
                $k++;           
            }
            $i += $value*$pixel_size;
        }
        else //rle
        {
            for ($j=0; $j<$value; $j++)
            {
                $out .= $data[$i] . $data[$i+1] . $data[$i+2];
                if ($pixel_size == 4) $out .= $data[$i+3];
                $k++;               
            }
            $i += $pixel_size;
        }   
    }
    return $out;
}
```

---

That's it, you will now get your TGA images perfectly converted. I'm giving you the full `tga.php` code so you can directly paste it and test it by yourself:

```
<?php

// Author: de77
// Licence: MIT
// First-version: 9.02.2010
// Version: 24.08.2010
// http://de77.com

function rle_decode($data, $datalen, $pixel_size)
{
    $len = strlen($data);

    $out = '';

    $i = 0;
    $k = 0;
    while ($i<$len)
    {
        dec_bits(ord($data[$i]), $type, $value);
        if ($k >= $datalen)
        {
            break;
        }

        $i++;

        if ($type == 0) //raw
        {
            for ($j=0; $j<$pixel_size*$value; $j++)
            {
                $out .= $data[$j+$i];
                $k++;           
            }
            $i += $value*$pixel_size;
        }
        else //rle
        {
            for ($j=0; $j<$value; $j++)
            {
                $out .= $data[$i] . $data[$i+1] . $data[$i+2];
                if ($pixel_size == 4) $out .= $data[$i+3];
                $k++;               
            }
            $i += $pixel_size;
        }   
    }
    return $out;
}

function dec_bits($byte, &$type, &$value)
{
    $type = ($byte & 0x80) >> 7;
    $value = 1 + ($byte & 0x7F);
}

function getimagesizetga($filename)
{
    $f = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    $header = fread($f, 18);
    $header = @unpack(  "cimage_id_len/ccolor_map_type/cimage_type/vcolor_map_origin/vcolor_map_len/" .
                        "ccolor_map_entry_size/vx_origin/vy_origin/vwidth/vheight/" .
                        "cpixel_size/cdescriptor", $header);
    fclose($f);

    $types = array(0,1,2,3,9,10,11,32,33);      
    if (!in_array($header['image_type'], $types))
    {
        return array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    if ($header['pixel_size'] > 32)
    {
        return array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    return array($header['width'], $header['height'], 'tga', $header['pixel_size'], $header['image_type']);
}

function imagecreatefromtga($filename)
{
    $f = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if (!$f)
    {
        return false;
    }
    $header = fread($f, 18);
    $header = unpack(   "cimage_id_len/ccolor_map_type/cimage_type/vcolor_map_origin/vcolor_map_len/" .
                        "ccolor_map_entry_size/vx_origin/vy_origin/vwidth/vheight/" .
                        "cpixel_size/cdescriptor", $header);

    switch ($header['image_type'])
    {
        case 2:     echo "Image is not compressed\n";//no palette, uncompressed
        case 10:    //no palette, rle
                    break;
        default:    die('Unsupported TGA format');                  
    }

    if ($header['pixel_size'] != 24 && $header['pixel_size'] != 32)
    {
        die('Unsupported TGA color depth'); 
    }

    $bytes = $header['pixel_size'] / 8;

    if ($header['image_id_len'] > 0)
    {
        $header['image_id'] = fread($f, $header['image_id_len']);
    }
    else
    {
        $header['image_id'] = '';   
    }

    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($header['width'], $header['height']);

    $size = $header['width'] * $header['height'] * $bytes;

    //-- check whether this is NEW TGA or not
    $pos = ftell($f);
    fseek($f, -26, SEEK_END);   
    $newtga = fread($f, 26);
    if (substr($newtga, 8, 16) != 'TRUEVISION-XFILE')
    {
        $newtga = false;
    }

    fseek($f, 0, SEEK_END);
    $datasize = ftell($f) - $pos; 
    if ($newtga)
    {
        $datasize -= 26;
    }

    fseek($f, $pos, SEEK_SET);

    //-- end of check
    $data = fread($f, $datasize);
    if ($header['image_type'] == 10)
    {
        $data = rle_decode($data, $size, $bytes);                   
    }
    if (bit5($header['descriptor']) == 1)
    {
        $reverse = true;    
    }
    else
    {
        $reverse = false;
    }    


    $i = 0;
    $pixels = str_split($data, $bytes);

    //read pixels 
    if ($reverse)
    {   
        for ($y=0; $y<$header['height']; $y++)
        {       
            for ($x=0; $x<$header['width']; $x++)
            {
                imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, dwordize($pixels[$i]));
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for ($y=$header['height']-1; $y>=0; $y--)
        {       
            for ($x=0; $x<$header['width']; $x++)
            {
                imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, dwordize($pixels[$i]));
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($f);         

    return $im;
}

function dwordize($str)
{
    $a = ord($str[0]);
    $b = ord($str[1]);
    $c = ord($str[2]);
    return $c*256*256 + $b*256 + $a;
}

function bit5($x)
{
    return ($x & 32) >> 5;  
}
```

And here is the output **`PNG`** image directly created from the script:
[image: Eyebrows PNG output]

And if you would prefer a direct download link rather than pasting the fixed code I give you here the full `php` file: https://www.sendspace.com/file/92uir9

At the end of the day, just change the **`tga.php`** file and everything will automagically work.

Comment: Perfect, I will let the original code owner know of this update

Comment: I haven't been able to reward, but I can in 1 hour. Just FYI

Comment: Awesome thanks :) I thought I would have to wait until 6 days.

Comment: @BHare How much time to wait now? :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the de77.com code, but with some additions:

```
<?php

// References:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709142/convert-32-bit-tga-to-png
// https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h
// http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/tga_specs.pdf
// http://www.paulbourke.net/dataformats/tga/
//
// This class development started with the following code:
// http://de77.com/tga-imagetga-imagecreatefromtga
// Author: de77
// Licence: MIT
// First-version: 9.02.2010
// Version: 24.08.2010
// http://de77.com
//
// C.. oct 2022
// I put the code in a class,
// I added the color-mapped formats,
// I added the 15b & 16b pixel-size formats.
//
// The following is supported:
//
//      Pixel-depths: 8b, 15b, 16b, 24b, 32b
//
//      Image Type      Description
//          0           No Image Data Included
//          1           Uncompressed, Color-mapped Image
//          2           Uncompressed, True-color Image
//          3           Uncompressed, Grayscale Image
//          9           Run-length encoded, Color-mapped Image
//          10          Run-length encoded, True-color Image
//          11          Run-length encoded, Grayscale Image
//
// NOTE: i commented out 16b-alpha code using:    //!
// It does not work, and images come out all transparent.

class uje_tga_class {
    private function rle_decode(&$data, $bytes) {
        $out = '';
        $i = 0;
        $len = strlen($data);
        while ($i<$len) {
            $b = ord($data[$i]);
            $type = ($b & 0x80);
            $count = 1 + ($b & 0x7F);
            $i++;
            // raw or RLE
            if ($type == 0) { //raw
                $size = $bytes*$count;
                $out .= substr($data, $i, $size);
                $i += $size;
            } else { //rle
                $s = substr($data, $i, $bytes);
                $out .= str_repeat($s, $count);
                $i += $bytes;
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }

    private function unmapcolors(&$data, $npixels, $colormapentrybytes, &$palette, $pixelbytes) {
        $out = '';
        for ($i=0, $i2=0; $i<$npixels; $i++, $i2+=$colormapentrybytes) {
            $idx = ord($data[$i2]); // $colormapentrybytes == 1 or 2
            if ($colormapentrybytes == 2) $idx += (ord($data[$i2+1]) << 8);
            $idx *= $pixelbytes;
            $out .= substr($palette, $idx, $pixelbytes);
        }
        return $out;
    }

    public function getimagesizetga($filename)  {
        $f = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        $header = fread($f, 18);
        $header = @unpack("cimage_id_len/ccolor_map_type/cimage_type/vcolor_map_origin/vcolor_map_len/" .
                        "ccolor_map_entry_size/vx_origin/vy_origin/vwidth/vheight/" .
                        "cpixel_size/cdescriptor", $header);
        fclose($f);
        $types = array(0,1,2,3,9,10,11,32,33);      
        if (!in_array($header['image_type'], $types)) return array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        if ($header['pixel_size'] > 32) return array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return array($header['width'], $header['height'], 'tga', $header['pixel_size'], $header['image_type']);
    }
    
    public function imagecreatefromtga($filename) {
        // open the TGA file for binary reading
        $f = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        if (!$f) return false;
        // read the file
        try {
            // read the TGA header
            $header = fread($f, 18);
            $header = unpack("cimage_id_len/ccolor_map_type/cimage_type/" .
                            "vcolor_map_origin/vcolor_map_len/ccolor_map_entry_size/" .
                            "vx_origin/vy_origin/vwidth/vheight/" .
                            "cpixel_size/cdescriptor", $header);
                            
            // check for supported tga formats
            switch ($header['image_type']) {
                case 1:     // color-mapped uncompressed
                case 2:     // truecolor uncompressed
                case 3:     // grayscale uncompressed       
                case 9:     // color-mapped run-length encoded
                case 10:    // truecolor run-length encoded
                case 11:    // grayscale run-length encoded
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new RuntimeException('Unsupported format: '. $header['image_type']);
            }
            
            $iscolormapped = ($header['image_type'] == 9 || $header['image_type'] == 1);
            $isrle = ($header['image_type'] == 9 || $header['image_type'] == 10 || $header['image_type'] == 11);

             // check for supported pixel sizes. ($header['pixel_size'])
            // But if this is a colormapped image, that "pixel_size" is in fact the width of each entry in the colormap.
            // For a colormapped image, the pixelsize is stored in $header['color_map_entry_size'].
            if ($iscolormapped) {
                if ($header['color_map_type'] == 0) {
                    throw new RuntimeException('Missing colormap');
                }
                $pixelbits = $header['color_map_entry_size'];
                // the entries in the colormap can be 8 or 16 bit wide
                $colormapentrybytes = $header['pixel_size']; // this is really the number of bits..
                if (($colormapentrybytes != 8) && ($colormapentrybytes != 16)) {
                    throw new RuntimeException('Unsupported colormap entry bits: '. $colormapentrybytes);
                }
                $colormapentrybytes /= 8; // ..now it's bytes
            } else {
                $pixelbits = $header['pixel_size'];
            }
            switch ($pixelbits) {
                case 8:                     // grayscale
                    $pixelbytes = 1;
                    break;
                case 15:                    // truecolor    5b blue + 5b green + 5b red + 1b dummy
                case 16:                    // truecolor    5b blue + 5b green + 5b red + 1b alpha
                    $pixelbytes = 2;
                    break;
                case 24:                    // truecolor
                    $pixelbytes = 3;
                    break;
                case 32:                    // truecolor
                    $pixelbytes = 4;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new RuntimeException('Unsupported pixel bits: '. $pixelbits);
            }

            // skip the image_id
            $header['image_id'] = ($header['image_id_len'] > 0)? fread($f, $header['image_id_len']) : '';

            // check whether this is a TGA v2.0
            $tgav2 = true;
            $pos = ftell($f); // store the current filepointer
            fseek($f, -26, SEEK_END); // (possibly) read the file footer
            $footer = fread($f, 26);
            if (substr($footer, 8, 16) != 'TRUEVISION-XFILE') $tgav2 = false;
            fseek($f, 0, SEEK_END);
            $datasize = ftell($f) - $pos; 
            if ($tgav2) $datasize -= 26; // pixeldata does not include any footer
            fseek($f, $pos, SEEK_SET); // restore filepointer

            // if color-mapped then read the palette.
            // The palette starts at the file-location where the image-data starts for the other formats.
            // So first read the palette, and then correct the final datasize.
            if ($iscolormapped) {
                $palettesize = $header['color_map_len'] * $pixelbytes;
                $pos = ftell($f) + $header['color_map_origin'];
                fseek($f, $pos, SEEK_SET); // set filepointer to palette
                $palette = fread($f, $palettesize);
                $datasize -= $palettesize;
            }

            // Read the image data.
            // If this is a colormapped image then this is not the pixeldata, but the indexes into the colormap.
            $data = fread($f, $datasize);
            
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //echo 'Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            return false;
        } finally {
            fclose($f);
        }

        // get the pixeldata
        if ($iscolormapped) {
            $npixels = $header['width'] * $header['height'];
            // colormapped images have the color-indexes encoded (pixeldata must be looked-up after RL decoding)
            if ($isrle) $data = $this->rle_decode($data, $colormapentrybytes);
            $pixeldata = $this->unmapcolors($data, $npixels, $colormapentrybytes, $palette, $pixelbytes);
        } else
            if ($isrle) { // possibly Run Length decode
                $pixeldata = $this->rle_decode($data, $pixelbytes);
            } else // uncompressed
                $pixeldata = $data;
        
        // create the image
        $im = imagecreatetruecolor($header['width'], $header['height']);
        
        // if the image has alpha data, then prepare for it
        imagealphablending($im, false); // no blending. Just copy the pixel
//!     if (!$iscolormapped && ($header['pixel_size'] == 32 || $header['pixel_size'] == 16)) {
        if (!$iscolormapped && ($header['pixel_size'] == 32)) {
            imagesavealpha($im, true); // be sure to save the alpha data
        } else {
            imagesavealpha($im, false);
        }
        
        // read pixel-ordering
        $toptobottom = (($header['descriptor'] & 32) != 0);
        $righttoleft = (($header['descriptor'] & 16) != 0);
        
        // process the pixels
        $i = 0;
        for ($y=0; $y<$header['height']; $y++)  
            for ($x=0; $x<$header['width']; $x++) {
                switch($pixelbytes) {
                    case 1:
                        $r = $g = $b = ord($pixeldata[$i]);
                        $col = imagecolorallocate($im, $r,$g,$b);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $r = (ord($pixeldata[$i+1]) & 0x7C) >> 2;
                        $g = ((ord($pixeldata[$i]) & 0xE0) >> 5) + ((ord($pixeldata[$i+1]) & 0x03) << 3);
                        $b = ord($pixeldata[$i]) & 0x1F;
                        $r <<= 3;
                        $g <<= 3;
                        $b <<= 3;
//!                     if ($header['pixel_size'] == 16) {
//!                         $a = ((ord($pixeldata[$i+1]) & 0x80) == 0)? 127 : 0; // 1b alpha means? transparent : opaque
//!                         $col = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, $r,$g,$b,$a);
//!                     } else {
                            $col = imagecolorallocate($im, $r,$g,$b);
//!                     }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $r = ord($pixeldata[$i+2]);
                        $g = ord($pixeldata[$i+1]);
                        $b = ord($pixeldata[$i]);
                        $col = imagecolorallocate($im, $r,$g,$b);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $r = ord($pixeldata[$i+2]);
                        $g = ord($pixeldata[$i+1]);
                        $b = ord($pixeldata[$i]);
                        $a = 127 - (ord($pixeldata[$i+3]) >> 1); // 128 alpha values with png transulency (where 127 = transparent, 0 = opaque)
                        $col = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, $r,$g,$b,$a);
                        break;
                }
                // set the pixel in the image
                $xp = ($righttoleft)? $header['width'] - 1 - $x : $x;
                $yp = ($toptobottom)? $y : $header['height'] - 1 - $y;
                imagesetpixel($im, $xp, $yp, $col);
                // next pixel in the pixeldata
                $i += $pixelbytes;
            }
        return $im;
    }
    
    public function imagetga($im, $filename) {
        list($width, $height) = array(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
        $tga = "\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" . pack('vv', $width, $height) . '  ';
        for ($y=0; $y<$height; $y++)
            for ($x=0; $x<$width; $x++) {
                $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
                $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
                $a = ($rgb >> 24) & 0x7F;
                $tga .= chr($b).chr($g).chr($r).chr((127-$a)*2);
            }
        file_put_contents($filename, $tga);
    }

    public function tga2png($tga_filename, $png_filename) {
        $im = $this->imagecreatefromtga($tga_filename);
        if (!$im) return false;
        //header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=image.png');
        //header("Content-type: image/png");
        imagepng($im, $png_filename);
        imagedestroy($im);
        return true;
    }
}

?>
```